# Entity framework beta only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, ado.net, installation

I have Visual Studio Team System 2008 RTM and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
When I try to install ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools Preview it says:

> ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools Preview
>   can only be installed if at least one
>   of the following Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2008 Beta 2 products is
>   installed: Visual Basic 2008 Beta 2
>   Express Edition, Visual C# 2008 Beta 2
>   Express Edition, Visual Web
>   Development 2008 Beta 2 Express
>   Edition, Visual Studio 2008 Beta 2
>   Standard Edition, Visual Studio 2008
>   Beta 2 Professional Edition, Visual
>   Studio Team System 2008 Beta 2 Team
>   Suite. Please install one of these
>   products, and then run this installer
>   again.

Is there a final version? All I want to do is to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project but the template is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my Visual Studio to SP 1. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out downloads for Visual Studio at:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/downloads/default.mspx